# How to replace __ieee754_exp_avx calls from source code or library?

Tags: c++, c, performance, gcc, optimization

__ieee754_exp_avx from libm*.so being used intensively in a certain source code, I would like to replace it with a faster exp(x) implementation?

custom exp(x):

```
inline
double exp2(double x) {
   x = 1.0 + x / 1024;
   x *= x; x *= x; x *= x; x *= x;
   x *= x; x *= x; x *= x; x *= x;
   x *= x; x *= x;
return x;
}
```

What gcc tags should I use to make gcc automatically use a custom exp(x) implementation? If it is not possible with gcc how can I do it then?

https://codingforspeed.com/using-faster-exponential-approximation/

Comment: Best bet is to profile the code, then put in exp2 calls by hand. (pow() will also call exp()). Often the code will fall over because of the lost accuracy, you need to do this sort of thing carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more like a workaround (*gainarie*):

Place `exp2` definition in a *.h* file:

```
//  exp2.h

#if !defined(__EXP2__H__)
#define __EXP2__H__

inline double exp2(double x) {
    x = 1.0 + x / 1024;
    x *= x; x *= x; x *= x; x *= x;
    x *= x; x *= x; x *= x; x *= x;
    x *= x; x *= x;
    return x;
}

#endif  //__EXP2__H__
```

Now, this file must end up included (whether directly or indirectly) in **all** the *.c(xx)* files that call `exp` - which might be a painful job if the existing codebase is large.

Then, when compiling the code, pass [-D](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html)(preprocessor definition) to *gcc* (I don't know the minimum version that supports this form; *v5.4.0* does) like this: `-D'exp(X)=exp2(X)'`.

**Note**: You no longer need *libm.so.**(`-lm`) at link time (at least not as far as `exp` is concerned), so you can remove it. Actually, it would be a good idea to remove it (temporarily - if you're using other math functions, permanently - otherwise), so that if there are any *.c(xx)* files that don't include *exp2.h*, the linker will spit an `exp` related *undefined reference* error (if using other math functions, after resolving all these errors by including *exp2.h* in the appropriate *.c(xx)* file you must add it back), otherwise you might end up with a mixture of `exp`/`exp2` calls in the code.

Answer (score 8):

Don't. This function is slower than the native implementation of `exp`, and is an extremely poor approximation.

First, the speed. My benchmarking indicates that, depending on your compiler and CPU, this implementation of `exp2` may be anywhere between 1.5x and 4.5x **slower** than the native `exp`. I'm not sure where the web site got their figures -- "360 times faster than the traditional `exp`" seems absurd, and is completely inconsistent with my tests.

Second, the accuracy. `exp2(x)` is reasonably close to `exp(x)` for `x ≤ 1`, but fails badly for larger values. For instance:

```
exp(1)   = 2.7182818
exp2(1)  = 2.7169557 (0.05% too low)

exp(2)   = 7.3890561
exp2(2)  = 7.3746572 (0.20% too low)

exp(5)   = 148.41316
exp2(5)  = 146.61829 (1.21% too low)

exp(10)  = 22026.466
exp2(10) = 20983.411 (4.74% too low)

exp(20)  = 4.851652e+08
exp2(20) = 4.0008755e+08 (17.5% too low)
```

While the web site you got this function from claims that there is "very good agreement for input smaller than 5", this is simply not true. A 1.21% difference (for `x=5`) is *huge*, and is likely to cause significant errors in any calculations using this approximation.

Comment: Good point. I will note that the author of the article that the OP got the implementation from led with "In neutral networks, where the math function `e^n` where `n` is usually small (less than 2, for instance), you can avoid the expensive `exp()` provided by math.h (for other programming languages, similar inbuilt system functions are provided)", so it is intended only for small arguments. I agree though that the speed claims are unreasonable. The recursive self-multiplication would yield a ton of data dependencies, making it very much limited by instruction latency.

Comment: I almost tried to Implement it, I guess I should be looking for a faster exp(x) implementation then.

Comment: @DominicGuana No. You should be looking for a way to optimize your application to reduce the number of calls to `exp()`.

Answer (score 3):

Simply don't. That function looks *way* slower than the built-in code, and it's definitely not OK with respect to precision.

If you need SIMD (single instruction, multiple data) optimized exp functionality, ie. you're not calculating a single value but a series of those, there's C libraries that do that for you. I'd like to highlight [VOLK](http://libvolk.org), the *Vector Optimized Library of Kernels*, a spin-off of the DSP-intense GNU Radio project.

It implements its own `expf` (single precision exponentiation – if you're willing to accept errors, there's certainly no reason to lug double precision floats around); here's how that compares on my machine :

```
RUN_VOLK_TESTS: volk_32f_expfast_32f(131071,1987)
a_avx completed in 60.119ms
a_sse4_1 completed in 62.052ms
u_avx completed in 60.376ms
u_sse4_1 completed in 62.131ms
generic completed in 2383.73ms
```

So, for 1987 iterations over a vector of 131071 elements, all the SIMD-optimized kernels were faster by a factor of 40 – that's pretty OK, but it's far away from the audacious 360x claim of the website you quote.

The source code of the expfast functions used can be found [here](https://github.com/gnuradio/volk/blob/master/kernels/volk/volk_32f_expfast_32f.h).

In its core, that implementation relies on the floating point representation – which is a pretty good idea.

It admits it has a 7% error boundary – that's pretty much!

Comment: Hi, I accepted the other answer but upvoted you as well for showing much faster exp(x) implementation, I think I will try to Implement this one based on Cristi's post.